# Example for backprop_lstm from rnn package

Tags: r, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I need an example with explanation for the arguments of

```
backprop_lstm(model, a, c, j, ...)
```

Comment: Hi! and welcome to Stack Overflow! In your console you can view the documentation for any function using `?backprop_lstm`, otherwise you can find documentation for the `rnn` package on CRAN [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/rnn.pdf).

Comment: I didn't find any example in either of both